# Find the critical values and point of the function.

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

Exercise.

A)$f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z-1)^2$. Find all the critical values and all $c \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $f^{-1}(c)$ is a smooth surface.

B)Now let $f(x,y,z)=z^2$ prove that $0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is a critical value  but $f^{-1}(0)$ is still a surface.

Sollution.

A) the jacobian $Df=2((x+y+z-1),(x+y+z-1),(x+y+z-1))$  so its zero at $(x,y,z)$ s.t $x+y+z=1$ Critical points.
So the critical values are all $y$ s.t the set

$f^{-1}(y)=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}:f((x,y,z))=y\}$ contains critical points. The only $y$ that its pre image contains critical points is the zero since  whatever critical point you input into the function its image is zero. So only critical value is $y=0$.

And  the $c \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t $f^{-1}(c)$ is a smooth surface are all the regular values of $f$ so its for all $c>0$

B) $Df=(0,0,2z)$ so  $f^{-1}(0)$ pre image of it contains $(x,y,0)$ x,y anything so it contains the critical point $(0,0,0)$ so its a critical value. But the set $f^{-1}(0)=\{(x,y,0)\}$ $x$,$y$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ is a surface cause it is easyl parametrized by the function $φ(x,y)=(x,y,0)$ which has its jacobian matrx degree 2. So its asurface parametrization.(is this reasoning  incomplete?).

Are the answers correct and complete?

Comment: Part A looks right to me but I have to admit I really do not know. I have no idea about Part B. One minor note, jacobian is normally spelled with a capital J.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $Df$ is as you say and so the set $\lbrace (x,y,z):x+y+z=1\rbrace$ is the set of critical points. When we plug these into $f$, the value of $f$ is always zero. So $0$ is the only critical value of $f$.

For the second part, I think you can get away with saying that $f^{-1}(0)$ is the $xy-$plane, which is a surface that doesn't need a chart.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for the first part we could say that $f^{-1} \{c\}$ is a normal surface for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$ because if $c=0$, then it's the plane $x+y+z-1=0$, witch as we know is a normal surface and if $c\neq 0,$ we note that every critical point of $f$ does not belong to set $f^{-1} \{c\} $, so by critical points theorem in this case, again,the previous set is a normal surface.